# Typo3/Typoscript : Content select, keep breaklines

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

This is my (very simple) code :

```
table = my_table
select.selectFields = teaser
renderObj = COA_INT
renderObj {

10 = TEXT
10.field = teaser

}
```

In fact a breakline is present in the teaser field (visibile in phpMyAdmin) but my code doesn't keep it. Is there a way to keep it when rendering the text via renderObj ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need breaklines in HTML you can use the `br` function in TypoScript. See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html?highlight=nl2br#br

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = teaser
10.br = 1
```

Comment: That's perfect ! Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you so muich.